# Django: how to exit in settings.py

Tags: python, django, exception

I have a Django website which has different settings for development and production (`DEBUG`/`SECRET_KEY`, etc). Production provides these settings with environmental variables. In the `settings.py` file I want to exit if the expected settings aren't given like so:

```
if not DEBUG and SECRET_KEY == DEFAULT_SECRET_KEY:
    sys.exit("SECRET_KEY must be set when DEBUG = False")
```

Is it correct to exit in the `settings.py` file like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should raise [`ImproperlyConfigured`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#improperlyconfigured), which will cleanly exit the application.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!